# Unable to draw lines on timelion visualization

Tags: kibana, timelion

I am currently running kibana 5.6.2 and I can't draw data as line in timelion.
Though, I'm able to draw my data with points and bars. For instance, .points(radius=3,weight=1,symbol=cross) would work but .lines(width=1,show=true) would not.
Yet, when I hover the mouse on the graph, it still manages to show the value of the specified point in the legend, even if no graph is displayed.

I should also say that I only have this problem when I use the "metric" parameter in the es function. I'm able to draw my data as lines when I don't use this parameter.

I tried to look for some config parameters in kibana management panel but I didn't found anything.
From what I've seen on the internet, nobody seem to have the same issue either with this kibana version.

If anybody has an idea on how I could solve this problem, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out I didn't search enough. For the records if anybody has the same problem, the solution can be found at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timelion-not-displaying/115503